# Pytest No Module named 'api'

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to run a pytest and i am getting this error, i have tried a couple of things but i could not fix it.

Could anyone give me a hand i am quite new to Python.

[image]
[image]

I have no idea what else i should do.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post the text itself formatted as code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for me problem.

1. I have added on my interpreter the path for my project root;
2. Set the variable PYTHONPATH pointing to my project;

Ta-dah! it worked.

Then I just fixed all the references of the imports based on my API.coro...